# What are the differences between running an application from Android studio, and its APK?

Tags: android

Recently I created an application that used one of  [my libraries](https://github.com/Nekrull/awesorm) (for those interested, DON'T USE IT YET, there's some memory leaks I need to still fix)

This library [uses_reflection to create a new instance](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) of the object it needs to load from the database

When I ran the application from android studio everything worked correctly

But when I built a signed APK (both release and debug) there was a problem because I had declared the objects that the ORM loads with package-internal constructors and the `awesorm` module did not have access to them.

Is there a list you can give me containing all the differences between running an application from android studio and using its generated APK?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference because the APK is built from the app gradle in the android studio. Your problem could be in the android device you are using in the real world. Or some permissions not granted to the APK by your device

Comment: I tried it on three different devices, one of which a tablet, and they all had the same problem, I fixed it by making the constructors public so that was definitely the problem